# Combining two blocks of Map loading from JSON

Tags: java

I have the below code and there is no issue with the code, just that I wanted to know is there a way I could combine both the try block into one.

```java
public void populateMap(Map data){

    String jsonData1 = readJSON("FILE_1_PATH");
    String jsonData2 = readJSON("FILE_2_PATH);

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonData1)) {
        try{
            Map<String,String> dataMap = ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonData1,POJO.class);
            data.put("file1",dataMap);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle exception
        }
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonData2)) {
        try{
            Map<String,String> dataMap = ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonData2,POJO.class);
            data.put("file2",dataMap);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may merge them easily enough and also the `Map` variables are not required, just inline the their value in the parameter passed to `data.put()`:

```
public void populateMap(Map data){
  String jsonData1 = readJSON("FILE_1_PATH");
  String jsonData2 = readJSON("FILE_2_PATH);

   try{
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonData1)) {
          data.put("file1", ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonData1,POJO.class));
        }  
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonData2)) {
           data.put("file2",ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonData2,POJO.class));
        }  
   }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle exception
   }
}
```

Note that the `Map` parameter is a raw type. Favor generic type instead of.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally move the second body of the try to the first.

```java
public void populateMap(Map data){

    String jsonData1 = readJSON("FILE_1_PATH");
    String jsonData2 = readJSON("FILE_2_PATH");
   
    try {
         if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonData1)) {
            data.put("file1", ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonData1,POJO.class));
          }

           if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonData2)) {
            data.put("file2",ObjectMapper.readValue(jsonData2,POJO.class));
           }
       } catch(Exception e) {
            //e.g., log exception e
        }
    }
   
    }
}
```

**Tip**: From Java 7 and above you can put more than one exception in the catch block

```java
    try { 
      // statement that could raise ExceptionTypeA  and/or ExceptionTypeB 
    } catch (ExceptionTypeA | ExceptionTypeB exception) {
      // statement to make use of handled exception
    }
```